# In "once you have", does 'have' mean 'understand'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Once you have a single adder for adding two bits of information, you can put together multiples of these adder circuits side by side to add together much larger numbers.
>   https://youtu.be/Sc3lh3D4rCw?t=160

In the above sentence, Does 'have' mean 'understand'?

Comment: Why would you think it means "understand" here?

Comment: In korean subtitle, it's translated as '이해하다'(understand). :o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"[Have](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/have)" means "possess", or "have control of". This is from an explanation of how logic circuits work, involving discussion of imaginary or hypothetical circuits, proceeding from simple to complex, in stages. The writer lays out a particular element (let us call it *x*), and then says 'once you have *x*, you can do something (which leads to the next level).